# if, else rock paper scissors game

Tags: javascript

I'm just doing some practice work for if, else statements and I've made a very simple rock paper scissors game, but for some reason it's not returning or console.logging anything! It's just returning `undefined`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong at all!

```
var answer = prompt("Rock, paper or scissors?");
if (answer === "rock") {
    console.log("tie");
}
else if (answer === "paper") {
    console.log("you win!");
}
else {
    console.log(answer === "You Lose!");
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check what are you getting in answer, try to print out answer string before the if statment to see what is it

Comment: Certainly your final condition isn't what you want:  console.log(answer==="You Lose!");

Comment: Do you need the strict checking, also - are you trying to log "true" or "You Lose!"?

Comment: The code would never return `undefined`.

Comment: It "works" fine for me: http://jsbin.com/zeyudiso/1/edit?js,console . It doesn't output `undefined` anywhere. Please provide a better explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me.  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ELw4/) showing it works.

What are you entering that isn't working?  Your code should probably be as follows however:

```
var answer=prompt("Rock, paper or scissors?");
if (answer==="rock"){
  console.log ("tie");
}
else if(answer==="paper"){
  console.log("you win!");
}
else {
  console.log("You Lose!"); //you shouldn't be setting the answer variable here, just outputting a console.log message
}
```

---

Edit: as Luke B pointed out, you weren't setting the variable, but you were printing out the result of the comparison.  I.e. The answer to `answer === 'you lose'` is always going to be `false` unless you typed `you lose` instead of rock or paper or scissors.

Comment: He wasn't setting the answer variable, he was just comparing it and printing a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
console.log(answer==="You Lose!");
```

to

```
console.log("You Lose!");
```

Thanks to William George

Answer (score 1):

It is returning undefined, but after returning the answer of the program. It is working just fine, just look closer to the console responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was just a matter of correcting some of my syntax and spacing. I did it again and it seemed to work!